# Push repository to new remote, one commit at the time

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I'm moving a repository to a new host, and for unfortunate historal reasons, a lot of large files are checked in (cocoa pods, images)

While I've used Git BFS to reduce the size to 940mb (from 2.4GB), it's still not enough to support the push to our internal deployment of BitBucket server.

So I'd like to push the commits one by one, from a specific point in history. The repository was originally ported from SVN, and broke the Git tree at that point in time (there's a graph that have a solid break about 5 years back)

It's only 4000 commits, so it's a reasonable amount to push one by one, but I can't find a good way to push *from* a given ref, rather than *to* a given ref.

So, is there any way to push from *commit-hash* to *commit-hash* (in my case, HEAD) to a (new) remote endpoint?

Comment: I don't know of any way to push a _commit_ directly but you might be able to create a new temporary branch, which you can reset to a commit, push the branch, reset it to the next commit, push it, and so on, until you're at master's commit, at which point you'd just have to push master and delete the temporary branch.

Comment: @tkausl `git push origin HEAD~1:refs/head/master` will push the commit before the current one to origin/master (and only that commit), but it doesn't work for a range of commits :/ So essentially I'm looking for a smart way of doing this for a full range.

Comment: Right, I forgot about `from:to` syntax... Well even if it doesn't work with a range, you could write a simple script to push one commit at a time. `git log --pretty=format:"%h" --reverse origin/master..master` gives you a list of commits origin/master is missing, iterate over them and push them one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, a little script to push one commit at a time might work. From the server's point of view it would look like one were working on the project, commiting and pushing continuously.

In bash, this should work:

```
for c in $(git log --pretty=format:"%h" --reverse --first-parent origin/master..master); do 
    git push origin $c:master
done
```

`--first-parent` is needed so it doesn't break on merge's. I tried it locally and this is what I got:

```
tobi@TOBIAS-PC:/mnt/d/test/git/r$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate
* d2d3264 (HEAD -> master) asdaskdj
*   9171144 Merge branch 'something'
|\
| * f85e25e (something) opjsdfk
| * 069b6f1 bla
* | f3c54df kjsdaflk
* | ca354e5 kjsdaflk
|/
* 6765170 asdf
* c1873cc (origin/master) initial commit


tobi@TOBIAS-PC:/mnt/d/test/git/r$ git log --pretty=format:"%h" --reverse --first-parent origin/master..master
6765170
ca354e5
f3c54df
9171144
d2d3264


tobi@TOBIAS-PC:/mnt/d/test/git/r$ for c in $(git log --pretty=format:"%h" --reverse --first-parent origin/master..master); do git push origin $c:master; done
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 235 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../b
   c1873cc..6765170  6765170 -> master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 244 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../b
   6765170..ca354e5  ca354e5 -> master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 244 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../b
   ca354e5..f3c54df  f3c54df -> master
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 762 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../b
   f3c54df..9171144  9171144 -> master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 274 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../b
   9171144..d2d3264  d2d3264 -> master


tobi@TOBIAS-PC:/mnt/d/test/git/r$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph
* d2d3264 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) asdaskdj
*   9171144 Merge branch 'something'
|\
| * f85e25e (something) opjsdfk
| * 069b6f1 bla
* | f3c54df kjsdaflk
* | ca354e5 kjsdaflk
|/
* 6765170 asdf
* c1873cc initial commit
```

You might also want to add a sleep in case the server gets overwhelmed by all these pushes to give it some time to process all this data; I don't really know whether it does anything further than just storing it on the disk, it might index it or something.